# Offsetting in a row in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Hi I am asking this because I have not seen it solved in any other Excel posts (Sorry if it has been. I have looked for about an hour and did not see anything, but please link if it has). This may be very simple, but I am having a hard time. I am using Excel 2010. Basically I am trying to offset the value by one column next to the value found in the row. So, for instance, I have several values:

Fname---Lname---State--Since---Licensed?--Since

John    Smith   MA  2012    Licensed    2014

Kathlyn Sanchez Not License 2012 HI    2009

I want to find the value to the right of what ever value is needed in that row only. I am trying to do this without ANY vba because the sheet will be used by others who are not versed in vba. So, in the case of John, I have a formula that pulls the state MA. And I need the value of what is next to it, so in this case 2012. But in the case of Kathlyn, I need the same thing, but the state is not in the same spot as it was in John's case. How do I offset if the value shifts in each row?

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Hi user3863137, vlookup (definitely tried it) won't help me here because what I use as a key changes for each row. My spreadsheet is 55k rows and about 90 columns wide, so being able to copy down a formula that will search for a key that is generated by another formula is what I hoping to find...like a formula to search within a  row's text, even if the row is several cells wide.

Comment: OK now I understand, the columns are not correctly structured. I cannot see any way of doing this since it's going to be difficult to determine what's a state, what's a result for Licensed etc without a reference point (e.g column header). Is there a reason for the data to be structured this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
        A                                           B   C
__________________________________________________________________________          
1   ||  John Smith MA 2012 Licensed 2014            MA  2012 
2   ||  Kathlyn Sanchez Not License 2012 HI 2009    HI  2009
```

if I understand right you have a table (like above) where in one column you have text such as "John Smith MA 2012 Licensed 2014" or "Kathlyn Sanchez Not License 2012 HI 2009". (lets call it column A) Then in another column you use some kind of formula to pull out a piece of text- in this case the state. (call it column B).

Then in column C you want to be able to pull out the next block of text to the right of text in column B,  **bound by spaces (!!)**. If that is the case use this formula:

`=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(B1,A1))+1),LEN(A1))),IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(B1,A1))+1),LEN(A1))-SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(B1,A1)))`

If not, than please explain better how "John Smith MA 2012 Licensed 2014" is actually stored in terms of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You were thinking along the right lines. You answer didn't get me what I needed (and this was my own fault) because I boiled down what I was doing, not wanting to get too complicated in my explanation. I eventually figured out how to get what I needed by assigning an arbitrary value to licensed and not licensed and then put in a few helper columns to get what I needed pulled out. Thank you everyone for posting answers. I am sorry that it took so long for my reply, things got extremely busy. I really appreciate the assistance on this!